# How to dynamically handle changes in a JSON object name that may change regularly, when building C# class to deserialize the JSON?

Tags: c#, json, object, properties, deserialization

my predicament is that I have to deserialize some JSON files provided by my company's software eng department, for me to use in a production environment, however some revisions of the JSON files have objects or keys where the name had been modified (E.g. **"EngineTemp"**:400 to **"EngTemp"**:400).

I can easily deserialize everything in C# when the names don't change, but I find myself having to modify my class property names or class names themselves, to match the JSON revisions (because I know they need to be the same). However, manually reading through each JSON file when it gets revised to check for name changes is very time-consuming, and some of these files have hundreds of objects.

Currently I have no way to ensure the software eng team keeps the same names from revision to revision, so I really hope there is a way to handle this in a less manual fashion.

I can't provide any snippets of the JSON unfortunately because it's proprietary information, but the above example is basically what I want to account for.

I appreciate all suggestions!

As mentioned previously, I haven't come up with any good way of handling this in code yet, since it deals with changing the actual class and property names in my C#, to match the revisions in the JSON if they are altered.

Comment: My first thought: Your company's software eng department should know better than that - changing property names is just a "No, no".

Comment: "How do I deal with breaking changes?" is highly specific to the software you're working with and your relationship with the developers of that software.

Comment: I definitely agree @PoulBak - hopefully they stop changing things soon, but the product is still in its final developmental stages and they're coming across typos, and still trying to settle on a few of their naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there's no really good solutions to this, but if there's a **limited number of names**, they use, then you can use a regex on the raw json data and replace with the name of your property. Then when you deserialize, the replaced name will work.

The regex can be rather simple:

```
(?<=")(EngineTemp|EngTemp|OtherName)(?=":)
```

It simply selects one of the known names surrounded by quotes and ending with colon `:`.

**Use it like this:**

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("path");

Regex jsonRegex = new Regex(@"(?<="")(EngineTemp|EngTemp|OtherName)(?="":)";

if (!jsonRegex.IsMatch(json)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR", "Could not find the name\nYou must scan the json manually");
}

string fixedJson = jsonRegex.Replace(json, "YourProperty");
```

Now you can deserialize the json without recompiling as long as the used name is in the regex.

The code shows a messagebox, if they have changed to an unknown name. Then find the new name add it to the list in regex.

**Edit**:

If you want to avoid recompiling when a new name is found, you can of course save the list in a text/json file. Then you only have to edit that, when a new name is found.

Comment: This is interesting! Currently I don't know what all the name variants may be, but this may be useful long-term after coming across a few, I can basically make a list of those, so it will catch anything that I encountered already.

Comment: It's likely that one programmer always use one name and another programmer uses another name. If that's the case this will work fine.

Comment: This is a good solution. The thing is that you have to pre-process the incoming json. Tradeoffs...

Comment: @CosminSontu: I agree, this is clearly a workaround. The only 'perfect' solution would be if they didn't change the json name in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You can deserialize to a dynamic object using `Newtonsoft` (`System.Text.Json` does not support dynamic well it seems).

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(inputString)!;
```

Then access your properties via duck typing

```
result.EngTemp
```

or via indexer

```
result["EngTemp"]
```

The point here is to define a property mapping in your appsettings.json which you can load in a `Dictionary<string, string> mappings`, and retrieve the properties with something like

```
result[mappings["EngTemp"]]
```

This would work by updating the mapping in `appsettings.json` and is applicable in scenarios where rebuilding the app or preprocessing the input is not an option.

Comment: Thanks for this, but the catch is that I wouldn't really know what the JSON object name gets changed to ahead of time, so I won't know what to use to access the property - basically I won't know if the name changed from EngineTemp to EngTemp, or something else, unless I physically read the JSON and see that it's different, so I won't know if to type "result.EngTemp" or "result.EngineTemp", etc... I hope this makes a little more sense :) Maybe I'm misunderstanding something!

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, but what I provided is the first step in solving the problem. You can parametrize your program via a config file (appsettings) where you define a dictionary mapping the latest names of fields with a reference name.
If that is not feasible, this is an impossible problem. You either know the variations in a field name (can be "A", "B" or "C") OR you know that since (for example) yesterday, the field is not called "A" but "B" in which case you just change the mapping in the configuration file (instead of editing code and recompiling).

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. I won't know the values of the keys ahead of time, but I'll see what I can do.